# Does a SharePoint Online user need a specific access level to be able to run C# code?

Tags: sharepoint-online, csom

I'm writing C# code to download files from a SharePoint Online site. Manually, I am able to access the `siteUrl`, navigate to the `folderPath`, and read/write on the files in there. However when I run my code below, I get this error:

`Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ServerUnauthorizedAccessException: 'Access denied. You do not have permission to perform this action or access this resource.'`.

I've also tried going the `OpenBinaryDirect` path, but I kept getting `404 Not Found` errors even though my urls are correct.

```
internal static void DownloadFilesFromSharePoint(string siteUrl, string folderPath, string tempLocation)
{
    string username = "my.username@company.com";
    string passwordFromForm = "password.from.form";

    var securedPassword = new SecureString();
    foreach (var c in passwordFromForm.ToCharArray()) securedPassword.AppendChar(c);
    ClientContext ctx = new ClientContext(siteUrl);
    ctx.Credentials = new SharePointOnlineCredentials(username, securedPassword);

    FileCollection files = ctx.Web.GetFolderByServerRelativeUrl(folderPath).Files;

    ctx.Load(files);
    ctx.ExecuteQuery(); //Error here    

    foreach (Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.File file in files)
    {
        FileInformation fileInfo = Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.File.OpenBinaryDirect(ctx, file.ServerRelativeUrl);
        ctx.ExecuteQuery();

        var filePath = tempLocation + file.Name;
        using (var fileStream = new System.IO.FileStream(filePath, System.IO.FileMode.Create))
        {
            fileInfo.Stream.CopyTo(fileStream);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: do you have Multi factor authentication enabled for your account?

Comment: Since the error is thrown after this part: `FileCollection files = ctx.Web.GetFolderByServerRelativeUrl(folderPath).Files;`, it has nothing to do with how you open/read each file, and thus `OpenBinaryDirect` won't solve the problem.

Comment: @AbdulHameed Nope, no multi-factor authentication.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found that the problem was that while my account had direct access to the specific folder in `folderPath`, it did not have access to the root folder of `Shared Documents` (this list is empty if I browse to it manually). It seems that `GetFolderByServerRelativeUrl` cannot access the folder directly and needs to traverse the path from the root to access it. After being granted access, the code now works.